# spring-mvc URL mapping issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to map my URL in spring mvc  as

> www.xyz.com\admin\addproduct, 
>   www.xyz.com\admin\usermanagement,
>   www.xyz.com\admin\report,

I tried in my web.xml as

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

I also read previous article about this 
[Spring MVC url-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816642/spring-mvc-url-mapping)

but when i add mvc resource in dispatcher-servlet.xml   file i got the following error

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>   - Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources] Offending resource: file
>   [D:/STS-3.0-Workspace/Sale365/WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-
>   servlet.xml]
>   - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources]

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
         <property name="viewClass"
             value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
         <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
     </bean>
     <mvc:annotation-driven />   <mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/admin/" />
```

Comment: Can you show the content of your dispatcher-servlet.xml file here?

Comment: <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/admin/" />

Comment: can you post the dispatcher-servlet in your question? The full xml file.

Comment: Please show the full content of the dispatcher-servlet.xml file. Including the schema definations.

Comment: Since i dont have more reputation, am not able paste whole xml. my dispatcher-servlet.xml is similar like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816642/spring-mvc-url-mapping

Answer (score 0):

You should not map  your resource/** to same URL that you map in Spring controller.

In controller, you are mapping /admin/usermanagement, /admin/report to spring methods and at same time defining resources to /admin/ path.

Change:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/admin/" />
```

to other path where your static resources are stored.. For example /WebContent/resources

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Let me know if that works.